# A good organization for subpackages import

Tags: python-3.x, python-import

I have a large JSON structure and I parse it into Python objects.
The hierarchy is:

```
class BaseCommand(...); class Command1(BaseCommand); ..., class CommandN(BaseCommand)
class Batch(batch_id: str, commands: List[Command])
class Bundle(batches: List[Batch])
```

I organized it into packages like this:

```
├── bundle
│   ├── bundle.py
│   ├── batch
│   │   ├── batch.py
│   │   ├── command
│   │   │   ├── command.py # a lot of commands here
```

My question is whether there is "the best" way to organize imports for the "bundle" package?

I had two ideas:

1. Make commands be importable from the "batch", and make the "batch" and commands importable from the "bundle". So you can do: `from bundle import Bundle, Batch, Command1, Command2`. So you can import everything public directly from the "bundle" package.
2. Force import from a specific subpackage. E.g.: `from bundle import Bundle`; `from bundle.batch import Batch`; `from bundle.batch.command import Command1, Command2`.

I find the [1] approach cumbersome. It requires you to duplicate the same imports.
I find the [2] approach to be less convenient for a client code. It should know from where to import what (understand the structure).